# Any difference in adding grandparent into MRO in python?

Tags: python, python-mro

Are there any side-effects of adding grandparent to the MRO? Purpose is I would like to get grandchildren classes by using `grandparent.__subclasses__()`

```
class A(object):
    def work(self):
        print 'A'


class B(A):
    def work(self):
        print 'B'
        super(B, self).work()


class C(B):
    def work(self):
        print 'C'
        super(C, self).work()

class D(B, A):
    def work(self):
        print 'D'
        super(D, self).work()

>>> C().work()
C
B
A
>>> D().work()
D
B
A
>>> A.__subclasses__()
[<class 'test.B'>, <class 'test.D'>]
```

Comment: What do you mean with side effects? You could determine the grandchildren by inspecting the MRO of each entry in `A.__subclasses__()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "adding grandparent to the MRO"?

Comment: @user2357112 `class D(B, A):`

Comment: @SimeonVisser how do you inspect each of grandchildren if you don't know `C` exists.  `A.__subclasses__()` only returns immediate children.

Comment: Breadth-first search. Keep calling `__subclasses__` on subclasses until you hit bottom.

Comment: Yes, repeat the process one more step to obtain all children of all children.

Answer (score 0):

We have come up a recursive function to work out the subclasses

```
def get_all_subclasses(cls):
    all_subclasses = []

    for subclass in cls.__subclasses__():
        all_subclasses.append(subclass)
        all_subclasses.extend(get_all_subclasses(subclass))

    return all_subclasses
```